# Using ModalPopupExtender in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

When using ModalPopupExtender inside a repeater, when the page loads, ALL of the popups appear without being called ( one for each item in the repeater) and then rapidly dissappear. 
 With this, the popup works , but the problem is these popups being showed at the beginning. The popup is an OK/CANCEL popup, that triggers a postback when OK is clicked and does nothing when cancel is clicked. It is loaded on page load so that it exists when the user clicks on a linkbutton on the repeater. When the user clicks on the linkbutton, our intention was taht the popup appear directly without doing a postback, and this was achieved , just that small problem that random parade of popups at the beginning!thank you in advance!

Comment: Turns out the HTML code and the CSS had conflicting codes and that made the popup appear!

Comment: please post is as an answer to you own question...

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to answer until now, sorry.
Turns out the HTML code and the CSS had conflicting codes and that made the popup appear!